# generateSpend originating from another node

Tags: corda

Can the following method be used to create a spend from Party B to Party A but when being called by a flow running on Party A?

This replaces the identity from the current node running the flow to Party B. However, it returns an exception for cashKeys:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Collection contains no element matching the predicate.
```

Method:

```
val (_, cashKeys) = Cash.generateSpend(serviceHub, builder, amount, partyBCert, forwardState.initiator)
```

PartyAndCertificate getter:

```
private fun getPartyBCert(): PartyAndCertificate {
    val partyBIdentityAndCertList = serviceHub.networkMapCache.getNodeByLegalName(CordaX500Name("PartyB", "New York", "US"))
            ?.legalIdentitiesAndCerts
            ?: throw FlowException("PartyB not found on network.")
    return partyBIdentityAndCertList.component1()
}
```

Stack trace:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Collection contains no element matching the predicate.
at net.corda.node.services.keys.PersistentKeyManagementService.getSigningKeyPair(PersistentKeyManagementService.kt:110) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.keys.PersistentKeyManagementService.getSigner(PersistentKeyManagementService.kt:85) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.keys.PersistentKeyManagementService.freshKeyAndCert(PersistentKeyManagementService.kt:83) ~[corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.finance.contracts.asset.Cash$Companion.generateSpend(Cash.kt:332) ~[corda-finance-3.3-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.finance.contracts.asset.Cash$Companion.generateSpend(Cash.kt:265) ~[corda-finance-3.3-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.finance.contracts.asset.Cash$Companion.generateSpend$default(Cash.kt:264) ~[corda-finance-3.3-corda.jar:?]
at com.template.flows.SettleCashFlow.call(SettleCashFlow.kt:117) ~[cordapp-0.1.jar:?]
at com.template.flows.SettleCashFlow.call(SettleCashFlow.kt:31) ~[cordapp-0.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96) [corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:44) [corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_191]
at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:62) [corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
```

The payee can change in my flow, is there another method for this scenario without having to split this into two separate flows?

Edit: stack trace for missing attachments

```
net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionVerificationException$MissingAttachmentRejection: Contract constraints failed, could not find attachment for: com.template.ForwardContract, transaction: B5606C7142B87D424DD0BDF8FF749987D53BF5B7D279795F32DA6AA4340D5403
at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction.verifyConstraints(LedgerTransaction.kt:96) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.transactions.LedgerTransaction.verify(LedgerTransaction.kt:79) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder.verify(TransactionBuilder.kt:143) ~[corda-core-3.3-corda.jar:?]
at com.template.flows.SettleCashFlow.call(SettleCashFlow.kt:119) ~[cordapp-0.1.jar:?]
at com.template.flows.SettleCashFlow.call(SettleCashFlow.kt:32) ~[cordapp-0.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96) [corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:44) [corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_191]
at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:62) [corda-node-3.3-corda.jar:?]
```

Is this due to missing keys from generateSpend? If yes, how do you retrieve the keys from the counterparty flow in a similar manner as the Party A -> B cash generation. verifyConstraints() says that transactions originating from another node require verification of attachments.

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace for the exception please?

Comment: @Joel updated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Cash.generateSpend` on behalf of someone else simply won't work. It expects to be called by the owner of the cash.

However, you can still add the cash in a single flow. The easiest thing is probably to send the `TransactionBuilder` to the counterparty and get them to call `Cash.generateSpend`. In pseudocode:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class Initiator(val counterparty: Party) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    override val progressTracker = ProgressTracker()

    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder()

        // TODO: Update TransactionBuilder.

        val counterpartySession = initiateFlow(counterparty)

        val updatedTxBuilder = counterpartySession
                .sendAndReceive<TransactionBuilder>(txBuilder)
                .unwrap { it -> it }

        // Check `updatedTxBuilder still has all the stuff you put in
        // originally, plus a new set of input/output cash states.

        // Finish flow using the `updatedTxBuilder`.
    }
}

@InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
class Responder(val counterpartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val txBuilder = counterpartySession
                .receive<TransactionBuilder>()
                .unwrap { it -> it }

        // Pass the correct arguments here.
        Cash.generateSpend(serviceHub, txBuilder, ...)

        counterpartySession.send(txBuilder)
    }
}
```

Note that you will need to add `TransactionBuilder` to the nodes' serialisation whitelists to send and receive instances of it in flows.

Comment: just to clarify, the transaction builder checking is done only for the updatedTxBuilder? i.e. the updated builder replaces the original. If yes, I assume any input states and commands added before this functionality become part of the updated builder? Verifying and signing the new builder raises the MissingAttachmentRejection exception for not finding an attachment. I haven't used the attachment functionality in this project and wouldn't explicitly expect a need to add an output state for Cash as it wasn't needed in my Party A to B version of the question.

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace you get when verifying and signing the new builder to the original question please? Then I can diagnose.

Comment: Added new trace.

Comment: Is the `ForwardContract` CorDapp included on both nodes?

Comment: Correct, present for A, B, notary and oracle.

Comment: And it's the exact same version of the CorDapp JAR included on all nodes?

Comment: Yeah, each node has corda-finance-3.3-corda.jar, cordapp-0.1.jar, cordapp-contracts-states-0.1.jar, Forward-Contract.jar.